# Laravel 5.6 Many to Many relationship - accessing child fields in view

Tags: laravel-5.6

I have a Many to Many relationship between User and Project. I am trying to list a users projects but can't access the child fields in a view:

Models

```
// Project
public function users() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\User')->withTimestamps();
}

// User
public function projects() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Project')->withTimestamps();
}
```

Intermediate table: project_user

```
user_id, project_id, timestamps
```

Controller

```
$projects = User::with('projects')->where('id', auth()->user()->id)->get();
return view('home')->with('projects', $projects);
```

View

```
  @foreach($projects as $project)
    - {{ $project->name}}
    <br>
  @endforeach
```

This returns no errors and no results

If I try `$projects->projects as $project` I get "projects" not available to this collection.

If I `return $projects` in the controller I get:

```
[
  {
  "id": 1,
  "first": "User",
  "last": "Name",
  "organization": "Organization",
  "phone": "5555555555",
  "email": "test@example.com",
  "created_at": "2018-03-22 20:16:20",
  "updated_at": "2018-03-22 20:16:20",
  "projects": [
    {
      "id": 10,
      "name": "Project One for User One",
      "description": "Project Description",
      "created_at": "2018-03-22 20:16:20",
      "updated_at": "2018-03-22 20:16:20",
      "pivot": {
        "user_id": 1,
        "project_id": 10,
        "created_at": "2018-03-22 20:16:20",
        "updated_at": "2018-03-22 20:16:20"
      }
    },
    ...
```

How can I access the child fields `name` and `description`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you do not have to query for the user, as it is already authenticated. If you use something like the [Debugbar package](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar), you can see that it will query the user for the current session.

So, to fetch the currently authenticated user, you can simply use:

```
$user = auth()->user(); // you can als use this in the view if you want.
```

In the controller, your code:

```
$projects = User::with('projects')->where('id', auth()->user()->id)- >get();
```

Will do a query to fetch **all** users with `id = auth()->user()->id` and it will **eagerload** all projects of those users (<- plural !!!).

So the `$projects` variable contains all the users with that id and it will attach all the projects in a subsequent query. Hence it is giving you an array of user objects, instead of the projects that you want. Which makes sense, since you are querying the User table.

Personally, I would do something like this in the controller:

```
$user = auth()->user();
$projects = $user->projects->get(); // doing this here will allow you to change get() to paginate() if you want.

return ('home')->with(['projects' => $projects]); // < either use compact as in the docs, or an associative array
```

Now in the view `$projects` will contain a Collection of projects, not users, and you can simply do:

```
@foreach($projects as $project)
  - {{ $project->name}}
  <br>   
@endforeach
```